# After using photoshop on Ubuntu, Alt+tab stops working properly

Tags: wine, photoshop

On my ubuntu machine (and the previous one as well) , I am using Ubuntu 16.04 
Alt+Tab works normally initially: it shows preview icons of all the windows and allows me to switch when I release, but once I use photoshop (via Wine), it stops working properly

It still switches, but no longer shows the preview. Apart from not showing the preview, it works as expected: it switches applications properly and if I press tab twice, it will switch to the next window

The preview is simply missing

The problem goes away if I restart lightdm or the system. Its only after using Photoshop+wine so far

Comment: Any Ubuntu 15.xx release is End of Life, unsupported. Please install a supported release, 16.04. Changes are the problem won't come back.

Comment: Nope, it happens in Ubuntu 16 as well.

Comment: If so, please edit your question. Otherwise it will be closed as unsupported.